# Extra white space overflowing the page when I adjust the width of my page. (CSS,HTML)

Tags: html, css

When I adjust my screen size to a smaller view, such as a phone view, there is this weird white box that appears underneath, it gets even longer the smaller I make the width. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I provided all of the css and html for this page.

Using the pesticide chrome extension, I can see that the white space is an HTML element. I'm not sure if that helps. Also here is a screenshot of the whitespace I am referring to.

[image: White Box]

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.websiteNav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.801);
  z-index: 1;
}

.websiteNavOptions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80%;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  gap: 5%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.homeitem {
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.reviewbutton {
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-left: 40vw;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(/images/6398749.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.white-rectangle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 150%;
}

.userInfo {
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  gap: 1em;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

#userNameTextBox {
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

#schoolNameTextBox {
  width: 59%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.userNameGroup {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vw;
}

.schooNameGroup {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vw;
}

.Questions {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.option {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 3%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding: 2%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.option input {
  display: none;
}

.option label {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.option label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  border: .17vw solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.10vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.option label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 101%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 4%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: rgb(76, 76, 160);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.10vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.option input:checked~label::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.76vw 4vw;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(124, 238, 200), rgb(45, 126, 99));
  font-size: .80vw;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.bottombutton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end
}

.bottom {
  margin-right: 20%;
  border: 0;
}

.review {
  width: 100%;
}

.finishbottombutton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.matchcontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.matchbackground {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10%;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 750px;
}

.matchcontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#studentImage {
  width: 45%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.imgAndContact {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3vh;
}

.matchTextContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#congratsmessage {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#student {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 2%;
  letter-spacing: 2vw;
}

#datatest {
  font-size: 2vw;
  ;
  word-spacing: 3vw;
}


}
```

```html
<nav class="websiteNav">
  <ul class="websiteNavOptions">
    <li class="logo"><a href="https://www.mydorm.com/">myDORM</a></li>
    <li class="homeitem"><a href="https://www.mydorm.com/" class="homelink">Home</a></li>
    <li class="reviewbutton"><a href="https://www.mydorm.com/colleges/dorm/photo/" class="button review">Leave a Review!</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">

  <div class="white-rectangle">

    <h1>Complete Survey Below </h1>
    <p> The survey below is calibrated with our state of the art technology that picks the perfect roommate 100% of the time.</p>

    <div class="userInfo">

      <div class="serNameGroup">
        <label for="userNameTextBox">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="userNameTextBox" placeholder="Enter Full Name" maxlength="20">
      </div>

      <div class="chooNameGroup">
        <label for="schoolNameTextBox"> School:</label>
        <input type="text" id="schoolNameTextBox" placeholder="Enter School Name" maxlength="35">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Questions">
      <h2> Question 1: Which of the following choices best matches the description of your sleep schedule</h2>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question1Choice1" name="Q1" value="Q1Answer1">
        <Label for="Question1Choice1">Go to sleep early, wake up early</Label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question1Choice2" name="Q1" value="Q1Answer2">
        <Label for="Question1Choice2">Go to sleep late, wake up early</Label>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question1Choice3" name="Q1" value="Q1Answer3">
        <Label for="Question1Choice3">Go to sleep early, wake up late</Label>
      </div>
      <hr width="95%" />
    </div>

    <div class="Questions">
      <h2>Question 2 : Which of the following best matches your cleanliness. </h2>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question2Choice1" name="Q2" value="Q2Answer1">
        <Label for="Question2Choice1">Dirty</Label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question2Choice2" name="Q2" value="Q2Answer2">
        <Label for="Question2Choice2">In the Middle</Label>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question2Choice3" name="Q2" value="Q2Answer3">
        <Label for="Question2Choice3">Clean</Label>
      </div>
      <hr width="95%" />
    </div>


    <div class="Questions">
      <h2> Question 3: What is your preferred room temperature</h2>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question3Choice1" name="Q3" value="Q3Answer1">
        <Label for="Question3Choice1">Cold</Label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question3Choice2" name="Q3" value="Q3Answer2">
        <Label for="Question3Choice2">Comfortable</Label>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question3Choice3" name="Q3" value="Q3Answer3">
        <Label for="Question3Choice3">Warm</Label>
      </div>
      <hr width="95%" />
    </div>


    <div class="Questions">
      <h2> Question 4: How comfortable do you feel sharing your belongings.</h2>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question4Choice1" name="Q4" value="Q4Answer1">
        <Label for="Question4Choice1">Dont touch my stuff!</Label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question4Choice2" name="Q4" value="Q4Answer2">
        <Label for="Question4Choice2">If you ask. </Label>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question4Choice3" name="Q4" value="Q4Answer3">
        <Label for="Question4Choice3">My stuff is your stuff!</Label>
      </div>
      <hr width="95%" />
    </div>

    <div class="Questions">
      <h2>Question 5: What is your preferred time to shower</h2>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question5Choice1" name="Q5" value="Q5Answer1">
        <Label for="Question5Choice1">In the morning.</Label>
      </div>
      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question5Choice2" name="Q5" value="Q5Answer2">
        <Label for="Question5Choice2">I am flexable, i have no preference</Label>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="Question5Choice3" name="Q5" value="Q5Answer3">
        <Label for="Question5Choice3">At night</Label>
      </div>
      <hr width="95%" />
    </div>

    <a class="ottombuttoncont" href="secondpagesurvey.html">
      <div class="bottombutton">
        <button class="bottom button" id="testbutt"> Continue to Next Page...</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's because you don't have enough content to fill out the viewport

Comment: So how do i shrink the viewport to only fill what i have?

Comment: Why do you specify your heights with percentages?

Comment: Not sure, i started learning css and html a week ago.  What should i be using instead?

Comment: Oh, good luck. I put your answer down, don't forget to rate me!

Comment: It did not fix the issue

Comment: you can't shrink the viewport. the viewport is the device screen you're viewing the page on @Joey

Answer (score 1):

You set the `font-size` of your writing based on the width of the page, this makes the smaller the width of the page, the writing becomes smaller, as the writing becomes smaller, your box also becomes smaller and this makes the bottom of the page look empty.

All you have to do is change the font size of the text, for example, to `pixels`.

try like this:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 20px;
}

p {
   font-size: 15px;
}

, ...
```

Comment: Its still not working, its still creating the white box at the bottom and its now stretching and distorting my text and questions

Comment: I dont what the white rectangle to take up the whole page, there is an image background behind it that the white rectangle is ontop of

Comment: I see what you are saying, but i am trying to make it responsive for mobile, with your suggested answer, now it just makes the text way too big for mobile.  Do you have any other suggested fix?

Comment: I just gave examples of numbers, you can subtract them.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: To solve the mobile problem, you can also use @media in css. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Answer (score 0):

You are not make any thing wrong but the content is shorter then the height of the window.
you can simply but the background-image on all html so the whitespace don't be clear to the user.

However I really recommend you to not use flex column if display block can replace the case.